# Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection)

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring

Hi I have having the exception above from a spring application, I am trying to connect to a clustered `Oracle` DB, but even if I try to connect to a single instance still have the same exception.

The bean definition is as thus:

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host_ip1)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host_ip2)(PORT=1521)))(LOAD_BALANCE=ON)(FAILOVER=ON)(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=db)))" />
            <property name="username" value="username" />
            <property name="password" value="password" />
            <property name="initialSize" value="10" />
     </bean>
```

The full stack trace is:

```
2012-02-13 13:18:45,084 1375 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory  - Initializing connection provider: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider
2012-02-13 13:18:45,207 1498 [main] WARN  org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2012-02-13 13:18:45,207 1498 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection)
2012-02-13 13:18:45,209 1500 [main] WARN  org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory  - Could not obtain connection metadata
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:1933)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1216)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:844)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:900)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:455)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4350)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:964)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:441)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    ... 75 more
```

Changing the ip addresses to their DNS names, I have a different exception, the stack trace is below:

```
2012-02-13 13:46:36,709 1685 [main] WARN  org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2012-02-13 13:46:36,709 1685 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Error preloading the connection pool
2012-02-13 13:46:36,710 1686 [main] WARN  org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory  - Could not obtain connection metadata
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Error preloading the connection pool
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1398)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:1933)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1216)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:844)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:900)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:455)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4350)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:964)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:441)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.addObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1059)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1395)
    ... 74 more
```

Comment: is the database server running on the given host and that port??

Comment: `host_ip2` seems an unlikely name for a databases server. Besides, why do you reference the same server twice in the list?

Comment: Sataru I connected via sqldeveloper and was fine, @nfechner I have updated it, and changing the ip address to dns names gave a different exception which I have included above, thanks

Comment: @SatadruBiswas now I restarted tomcat and the old exception reappears, I am so confused here

Comment: Can you please post the jars in your projects buildpath.

Comment: @royjavelosa the jars are as below:
annotations-api.jar,catalina-tribes.jar,jasper-el.jar,mysql-connector-java-3.1.12-bin.jar,ojdbc14_g.jar,tomcat-i18n-es.jar,catalina-ant.jar,classes12dms.jar,jasper.jar,nls_charset12.jar,    ojdbc14.jar,servlet-api.jar,tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
catalina-ha.jar      classes12.jar        jasper-jdt.jar  ojdbc14dms_g.jar                     ojdbc5.jar     tomcat-coyote.jar  tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
catalina.jar         el-api.jar           jsp-api.jar     ojdbc14dms.jar                       ojdbc6.jar     tomcat-dbcp.jar    xstreams.jar

Comment: I had to go look for ojdbc compatible with version on oracle that was installed this fixed my problem, my bad was thinking one ojdbc would work for all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had to go look for ojdbc compatible with version on oracle that was installed this fixed my problem, my bad was thinking one ojdbc would work for all

Answer (score 2):

Just check tsnnames.ora and listener.ora files. It should not have localhost as a server. change it to hostname.

Like in tnsnames.ora

```
LISTENER_ORCL =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
```

Replace localhost by hostname.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error with Tomcat 8.0 / MySQL . Changing the jdbc url value from localhost to 127.0.0.1 resolved the issue.

Comment: Completely different issue; in MySQL a connection to 'localhost' is always treated as a filesystem socket rather than a network socket.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and ended up solving it by upgrading my Oracle ojdbc driver to a version compatible with the Oracle database version

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the error "Error preloading the connection pool" while using Oracle 10g Express Edition with my Spring and CAS based application during login.

My CAS based application only has classes12.jar in its classpath, Placing ojdbc14.jar in  the classpath has resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the cases issue  is due to problem with hostname . Please check the hostname ,some times database team will maintain many hostname for connecting same database . Please check with database team regarding this connection issue.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the "localhost" with IP Address (Database server's public IP Address) in the jdbc Url then it worked.

```
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:<user>@//localhost:1521/<Service Name>";

↓↓

jdbcUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:<user>@//<Public IP Address>:1521/<Service Name>";
```

Comment: Then there is an issue with your DNS config. Unless you manage the infrastructure or have been told to do this by whoever does, this is bad and dangerous.